# Turn on a led with ARM in assembly language

Tags: arm, assembly

How do I convert this C++ code for turning on one LED into ARM assembly language for the LPC2124?

```
#include <lpc17xx.h>

void delay_ms(unsigned int ms)
{
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<ms; i++) 
        for (unsigned int j=0; j<20000; j++);
}

int main()
{
    LPC_PINCON -> PINSEL0 = 0x00000000;
    LPC_GPIO0  -> FIODIR  = 0x0001;

    while(1)
    {
        LPC_GPIO0->FIOSET = 0x0001;
        delay_ms(100);
        LPC_GPIO0->FIOCLR = 0x0001;
        delay_ms(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Can you tell us what happens when you try to run the code? Does the arm become armed? Do you get armed? Is anyone armed? Or is the problem that you got it in C++ and want to convert it to assembly language?

Comment: Could you please put your code in a code block.  You can't JUST copy-paste code on StackExchange, you need to mark it up manually.

Comment: You could look at what the compiler emits, that's similar to someone here doing it.

Comment: Off-topic, but that is almost C.  The only thing AFAIK that makes this C++ is that you can't declare variables inside the for loop condition (inside the parentheses).

Comment: @HarrySvensson that's a correct code i just wanna convert it to assembly

Comment: I didn't know that this site converted C++ code to assembler code. I also didn't know that this was a wanna site.

Comment: "I need to turn on one led with lpc2124 with assembly language".  Learn its assembly language, and learn the address mappings for the GPIO pins, and how to use the timers.  The code looks fairly simple.  Try rewriting it in assembler before you ask us for help.

Comment: You want this to run on an LPC2124, but include a header intended for LPC17xx?

Comment: @OskarSkog C99 should be able to declare variables inside loops, some conventional compilers that support C89 won't allow. Also to  OP; if you want to turn on the LED in assembler, either compile the C code (don't need C++ for this) or assemble an assembly program. Now you're doing neither, and seems like you're asking us to do your work.

Comment: "How do I convert this C++ code for ... into ARM assembly ...?" - With a compiler. That's what compilers are for. And that's not C++, its just C.

Answer (score 4):

> How do I convert this C++ code for turning on one LED into ARM
>   assembly language for the LPC2124?

You can't. Others can. But you can't. (Someone else may do it for you. But then it would be their effort and not yours.) The reason is this: For you to be able to even ask this question, I can adduce the following:

1. You don't know ARM machine code.
2. You don't know ARM assembly coding.
3. You don't even know where to get an assembler tool for ARM.
4. You don't understand the linking process.
5. You don't understand what a locator does or how to apply one.
6. You have never even looked at the assembly equivalent of C/C++ code.
7. You don't know what a stack frame (aka activation record) is.
8. You don't know how parameters might be passed in any given compiler, or even know to ask the question.
9. You don't know how to interpret hardware registers and how to rationally assign them purposes in your assembly program.
10. You don't know what the basic program model might look like under either a von Neumann or Harvard architecture.
11. You don't know about scoping, variable lifetime, heaps, etc.
12. You don't really know how to initialize hardware or probably how to read a functional block diagram in a datasheet or even how to read a datasheet.

In short, pretty much clueless. Instead, you've been depending on all this knowledge held by others and spoon fed to you. Which pretty much means you can't convert that code into assembly. Not now and not for a while.

---

ARM is often both well-documented but also intimidating in terms of making sure you have all of the necessary documents, as it is often broken up into not only a variety of functionally isolated documents but also where a manufacturer may refer you to ARM itself for some of the documentation they don't provide. Plus, it's a good idea to take advantage of what others have written, too. So it can take some time just to get all the needed pieces, or even to know what all the needed pieces will be. Plan some time for this.

You will also need to have some example code to study. It helps a lot to pick up some samples and study them as you read the other documents.

You will need manuals on the tools (assembler, linker, locator, librarian, debugger, etc.) and their generated outputs and what those outputs do for you (map files, object files, library files, etc.) You will need to understand how each part of the toolchain works together to create a final result. You will need other tools to load the code into your device (though you may already have these in hand, you may need to understand better how they function with the output of an assembler toolchain.)

And that's only getting started.

---

I don't mean to make it sound complicated. It's actually not as bad as it sounds. That is, if you already understand the ideas of some things, anyway. If you have a context from prior experience, it goes a long, long way in allowing you to focus and organize your steps ahead and plow through them. Then it's just "a process" of sorts. One step, then the next. But it is still work, even then.

Given how little you know, adduced from the way you write your question and the question itself, you have a bit of a road ahead. Don't let that stop you. It can be well worth the time. But you won't be converting that code to assembly on your own anytime soon.